# How to add jpeg support in Fedora 22 so that R can use it?

Tags: linux, fedora, r, dependencies, rstudio

I got an error looking as follows:

```
    gcc -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic  -c read.c -o read.o
In file included from read.c:1:0:
rjcommon.h:11:21: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:134: recipe for target 'read.o' failed
make: *** [read.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘jpeg’
* removing ‘/home/-/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/jpeg’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jpeg’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘jpeg’ is not available for package ‘ggmap’
* removing ‘/home/-/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/ggmap’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggmap’ had non-zero exit status
```

So basically R can't get jpeg support as far as I understand it, but I have installed this:

```
http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=openjpeg-libs%28x86-32%29
```

For Fedora 22 x64 and it does not solve the problem. Is there any solution? What am I missing?

Comment: See this: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problems-installing-jpeg-package-td4702363.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing development package for the JPEG library. `openjpeg-libs` is a runtime package, meaning it doesn't contain the header files needed when compiling source files that are using the library.

However, the `openjpeg-libs` is not the one you need, the right one based on a rpmfind.net search for the missing `.h` file is [`libjpeg-turbo-devel`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=%2Fusr%2Finclude%2Fjpeglib.h&system=fedora). And of course, you'd also need the corresponding [run-time lib `libjpeg-turbo`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libjpeg-turbo&system=fedora).

Comment: Yes, on Fedora 22, `jpeglib.h` is definitely provided by `libjpeg-turbo-devel`